# Implementing swipe gesture in xCode obj. C

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am fairly new at programming in objective c and am trying to implement swipe gestures to swipe between view controllers on an app I am creating in xcode. I'm trying to make it so when I swipe left, it switches to another view controller that I have named "SecondViewController". I have created the outlet and action for my gesture in my .h file, and in my .m file I have added the following code:

```
- (IBAction)swipeLeft:(id)sender {

ViewController *SecondViewController = [[ViewController alloc] init];
[self presentViewController:SecondViewController animated:YES 
    completion:nil];
```

Whenever I run the app, nothing happens when I swipe. Is there something that I have not yet done that I need to do to make this work?

Comment: you can use pageviewcontroller for handle this. maybe it good then.

Answer (score 2):

There are basically four Swipe Gesture is available:

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight
UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft
UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp  
UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionDown
```

You can use any of it as per your requirement. To adding any of above gesture, you can alloc Gesture and then add it to your particular view. So as soon as you swipe detected, it will call relevant method.

For Example for Right and Left gesture:

```
 UISwipeGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizerRight = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeHandlerRight:)];
    [gestureRecognizerRight setDirection:(UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight)];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizerRight];

    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizerLeft = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeHandlerLeft:)];
    [gestureRecognizerLeft setDirection:(UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft)];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizerLeft];

-(void)swipeHandlerRight:(id)sender
{
}

-(void)swipeHandlerLeft:(id)sender
{
}
```